# virtual function const vs virtual function non-const

Tags: c++

```
class Base
{
   public:
   virtual void func() const
   {
     cout<<"This is constant base "<<endl;
   }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
   public:
   virtual void func()
   {
     cout<<"This is non constant derived "<<endl;
   }
};


int main()
{
  Base *d = new Derived();
  d->func();
  delete d;

  return 0;
}
```

Why does the output prints "This is constant base". However if i remove const in the base version of func(), it prints "This is non constant derived"

d->func() should call the Derived version right, even when the Base func() is const right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504300, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827374, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152799.

Comment: possible duplicate of [virtual function that is const in the base class and not const in the derived](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504300/virtual-function-that-is-const-in-the-base-class-and-not-const-in-the-derived)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
 virtual void func() const  //in Base
 virtual void func()        //in Derived
```

`const` part is *actually a part* of the function signature, which means the derived class defines a *new* function rather than *overriding* the base class function. It is  because their signatures don't match.

When you remove the `const` part, then their signature matches, and then compiler sees the derived class definition of `func` as *overridden version* of the base class function `func`, hence the derived class function is called if the runtime type of the  object is `Derived` type. This behavior is called runtime polymorphism.

Comment: I am confused here. If both are treated as 2 different functions, why does the d->func() call the derived version, as there is no const applicable here.

Comment: Right. And in fact it's quite common for a class to define two identical functions, one `const` and one not.

Comment: @vamsi, the definition of `Base` only contains one function, so that's the one that's called.

Comment: @vamsi Because you have a pointer to Base*. In the Base interface, there is only one overload of 'func' available, and that's read-only (const). The fact that it's read-only is irrelevant when it's the only one the compiler will see through a base pointer. If both functions were defined in Base, then naturally the compiler would choose the non-const one. The derived one isn't even available to call in this context.

Comment: Weighing in on an old question incase people find this. With C++11 now remember to add `override` to all the functions you expect to actually override and the compiler will tell you when they don't, like in this case.

Comment: the actual object pointed by d is for class 'Derived'. Why isnt the vtable containing the methods corresponding to those? If yo uhave a const and a non const function, the vtable shows entries corresponding to both the functions in vtable. Why isnt it in this case?

Comment: @Abhinav the vtable *does* have both functions but the pointer is of type `Base *` so only *one* of them can be reached, because the definition of `Base` only contains one function. If the function signatures matched then both functions would be in a single vtable entry and the function would be properly polymorphic.

Answer (score 5):

`virtual void func()` is actually of a different signature than `virtual void func() const`. Thus you didn't override your original, read-only base function. You ended up creating a new virtual function instead in Derived.

You can also learn more about this if you ever try to create pointers to member functions (PTMFs), but that's a rare necessity (might be good for study or practice, however).

The override keyword in C++11 is particularly handy to help avoid these kinds of mistakes. The compiler would then tell you that your definition of 'func' in derived does not override anything.

Answer (score 4):

No, because `virtual void func()` is not an override for `virtual void func() const`.