# C++ pure virtual const member function

Tags: c++

How can I declare a pure virtual member function that is also const? Can I do it like this?

```
virtual void print() = 0 const;
```

or like this?

```
virtual const void print() = 0;
```

Comment: I'd guess `virtual void print() const = 0;`

Comment: See this stack overflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488168/virtual-function-const-vs-virtual-function-non-const

Answer (score 70, accepted):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/const-cpp#const-member-functions):

> To declare a constant member function, place the `const` keyword after
>   the closing parenthesis of the argument list.

So it should be:

```
virtual void print() const = 0;
```

Comment: What is the " = 0 " for?

Answer (score 21):

Only the `virtual void print() const = 0` form is acceptable.  Take a look at the grammar specification in C++03 §9/2:

> *member-declarator*:
>       *declarator pure-specifier<sub>opt</sub>*
>       *declarator constant-initializer<sub>opt</sub>*
>       *identifier<sub>opt</sub>* `:` *constant-expression*
>
> *pure-specifier:*
>       `= 0`

The `const` is part of the *declarator* -- it's the *cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* in the *direct-declarator* (§8/4):

> *declarator*:
>       *direct-declarator*
>       *ptr-operator* *declarator*
>
> *direct-declarator*:
>       *declarator-id*
>       *direct-declarator* `(` *parameter-declaration-clause* `)` *cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> exception-specification<sub>opt</sub>*
>       *direct-declarator* `[` *constant-expression<sub>opt</sub>* `]`
>       `(` *declarator* `)`

Hence, the `= 0` must come after the `const`.

Comment: I prefer this answer, since it refers to the c++ specification, instead of the microsoft one.

Answer (score 6):

Of course you can. The correct syntax is:

```
virtual void print() const = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:-

```
 virtual void print()  const = 0;
```