# virtual method overridden issue with unique_ptr move semantics

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, virtual, unique-ptr

It looks like in below code snippet virtual method overridden is not happening with Adapter object and both Target and Adapter object is showing same output.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    class Target
    {
       public:
        virtual std::string getResponse ()   
      {
              return "simple response";
       }
   };
    
    class Adaptee
    {
     public:
       std::string getSpecialRequest ()   
      {
              return "Special response";
       }
    };
    
    class Adapter:public Target
    {
       unique_ptr < Adaptee >  m_adaptee;
     public:
        Adapter (unique_ptr < Adaptee >  adaptee )  :  m_adaptee (std::move (adaptee))   
      {
          // m_adaptee = std::move (adaptee);
       }
         std::string getResponse ()  const 
      {
           return m_adaptee->getSpecialRequest ();
       }
     };
    
    class client
    {
                        
          unique_ptr < Target >  m_target;
        public:
          client ( unique_ptr < Target > target)    
      {
                m_target = std::move (target);
           std::cout << m_target->getResponse ();
        }
     };
    
    int main ()
    {
          
          unique_ptr <Target> oj =  make_unique <Target> ();
          unique_ptr <Adaptee > oj1  =  make_unique <Adaptee> ();
          unique_ptr < Target > oj2  = make_unique<Adapter> (std::move(oj1));
          client instance (std::move (oj));
          client oj3 (std::move (oj2));
          return 0;
    }
```

output : simple response
simple response

expected output : simple response
special response;

it looks like it is issue of object transfer-ship from Target to Adapter object.Please suggest.

Comment: This function std::string getResponse ()  const  is not a virtual function.

Comment: Thanks , You have saved my day . I am wondering even chatgpt also couldn't find this mistake and giving multiple solution to fix this which is not working at all . It was my mistake that I forgot to use override keyword in Adapter class

Comment: The function in the base class is not `const`.  The one in the derived class is.   So the signatures don't match, and your derived class is NOT overriding the inherited virtual function.

Comment: Se dupe: [virtual function const vs virtual function non-const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488168/virtual-function-const-vs-virtual-function-non-const). Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to search and then research and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.

Comment: I wasn't aware about my mistake and this kind of issue can be caught using code review .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getResponse` declared in the class `Adapter`

```
  std::string getResponse ()  const 
  {
       return m_adaptee->getSpecialRequest ();
  }
```

is not a virtual function that overrides the function with the same name in the class `Target`

```
class Target
{
   public:
    virtual std::string getResponse ()   
  {
          return "simple response";
   }
```

};

because the functions differ in the qualifier `const`.

Always use the specifier `override` in declarations of virtual functions that override other virtual functions. In this case the compiler can issue an error if a function actually does not override other virtual function.

For example if you would write

```
  std::string getResponse ()  const override
  {
       return m_adaptee->getSpecialRequest ();
  }
```

then the compiler issued an error and it would be clear what is the problem.